# Trim function and WorksheetFunction.Trim do not remove leading or trailing spaces

Tags: excel, vba, trim

I copied some data from a website in a worksheet and noticed some cells in addition to the expected value, also contained a trailing space.

I wanted to remove these spaces due to causing troubles to my code. I spotted a specific cell having this space and tried:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value = Trim(Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value)
```

- The space was still there.

Then I tried:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value)
```

- Still no luck.

The `Replace` function not only removes leading and trailing, but also the spaces inside the string:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value = Replace(Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value," ","")
```

- Some cells contained two words so this was not an option.

I could check the last character for being a space and remove it for every cell, but this did not seem as an elegant solution and the main question remains: Why `Trim` functions do not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending a looooong time searching on the net, I found out [here](https://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown/issues/16) that there is also another character for space, the output of `Chr(160)` and for some reason `Trim` functions ignore it. So the solution in my case was *firstly* replace all these 'different' spaces *and then* trim values:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value = Replace(Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value, Chr(160), " ")
Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value = Trim(Worksheets(2).Range("D17").Value)
```

In case you encounter a similar problem and run into a different-from-`Chr(160)` 'unknown' character, you can find out what this character is, by isolating this character and using the `Asc` function.

Comment: Ascii 160 is a non-breaking space.

Comment: And you're not the first to meet this with frustration, https://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/ascii-160-or-non-breaking-space/

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I am sure I 'm not the first. I hope I 'll help to be the last.